# How do I restructure the htaccess to allow for the home page?

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, url

Ok so I have a site that has tons of pages and I want to create a php file fore each one...this works great..here is what i have, code wise

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

here is my index.php file

```
$parts = explode('/', $_REQUEST['url']);

switch ($parts[count($parts) - 1]) {
    case 'restaurant':
    include "pages/restaurant.php";
        break;
    case 'retail':
    include "pages/retail.php";
        break;  
        .......
        .......

}
```

this works great and if i visit the url `http://someurl.com/restaurant` the proper file in pages/restaurant.php pulls up. The only problem is the home page  `http://someurl.com` when i visit it i get a:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /structure on this server.
```

Is there a way to fix this in the .htaccess to address this issue and should i create a file maybe called home.php in the pages folder or should i just put the content of the home page in the index file in an else condition...any ideas

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify a default switch case?

```
switch ($parts[count($parts) - 1]) {
case 'restaurant':
include "pages/restaurant.php";
    break;
case 'retail':
include "pages/retail.php";
    break;  
default:
include "pages/default_page.php";
    break;
    .......
    .......
}
```

Comment: I cant even get to the page....the browser wont render anything if there is nothing after the .com

Comment: you dont understand i cant even get to the php because the Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /structure on this server.

Comment: @Tamer -- there should be at least slash after .com eg.g `http://www.example.com/`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use this rule somewhere before existing rules:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?url=home [L]
```

2. Create `pages/home.php`

3. Add this to your switch statement:

```
case 'home':
include "pages/home.php";
    break;
```

**P.S.** I do not recommend using `default:` to handle home page. `default:` should be used to handle 404 page / unknown pages **ONLY**.

Comment: I cant do that for seo reasons...i need someurl.com and not somesite.com?url=home

Comment: @Tamer -- that is EXACTLY the same syntax as you already using -- see your own rule. How come SEO is OK for them and becomes broken/not good for this??

Comment: so if someone enters in somesite.com how do i get it so stop the Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `default` statement in that `switch`? My bet is you don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Do you have this code in your httpd.conf or .htaccess?

It seems like your default file is not index.php